# Java generic declaration based on json

Tags: java, json, dataweave

I am trying to define java generic type in method and I am not able to do so. I went through lot of posts but haven't figured it out.

I have a JSON which will be converted to java `LinkedHashMap` by Mule Dataweave. Here is simple JSON

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": {
      "c": [{
          "name": "abc"
        },

        {
          "name": "xyz"
        }
      ],

      "d": "e"
    },

    "f": "g"
  }
}
```

Now I want to use that JSON converted to `LinkedHashMap` in java method.
I tried something like

```
public void test(LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap>> payload)
```

but the value can be recursive `LinkedHashMap` until I get key and value as String. I don't know how deep it can go as it is based on JSON response. How can I define it in java generics?

Comment: Generics have to be static at compile time, you can't do this over Generics

Comment: There are libraries providing JSON data structures no need to re-invent the wheel. E.g. Jackson, Gson,  json-io or Genson.

Comment: Can you give more context on why do you need to do that in Java? DataWeave already does the conversion automatically.

Comment: dataweave coverts the json to map, but i need to run validations on the map. in raml i can just specify the enums , but cant run validation. example i have to enum in raml says [usa, england, germany] and other enum as [newyork, london, berlin]. i need to run validation where in first enum is usa, the second enum value should be newyork. this is just a sample, i have more complex validations that needs to runs on json payload.

Answer (score 0):

As Java Does not support Union Types you can not model this other than

```
public void test(LinkedHashMap<String, Object> payload)
```

Where you know that an Object is Either a Map<> or String or List.